# technology to switch html to php in a website

Tags: php, html

after some days learning html and css i have got used to programming in html, my skills are improving and i could program a site with css which looks very good... now my next step is to learn using a current technology for web2.0 like php

all my pages end in html extension but i want to change them to php extension so the site will be more current and work with better technology.

i have read many manuals but i cannot find how to switch my work from html into php technology
link to the work http://preferredmerchantservices.net/
thanks

Comment: php code does not work by setting the php extension.you really have to do some research on what is php

Comment: HTML and CSS are *not* programming languages. PHP *is*, though, and understanding the difference is pretty key to your 'problem'.

Comment: well technically PHP is a scripting language right?

Comment: PHP dynamically generates HTML and what HTML it creates depends on what you want your website to do. First, please tell us why you want to convert your site to using PHP and what features you want to implement on it. That will help us give you better responses.

Comment: scripted or compiled, both are programming, FYI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a programming language. HTML and CSS are markup languages. You don't convert HTML to PHP. PHP can be used to generate HTML, like it can be used to generate many other formats.

Changing your file extensions from *.html to *.php is not going to magically make your "current." Also, another thing to consider is that many programmers will name their PHP documents differently based on the content contained within them. For example, any files I write that contain nothing but PHP and don't directly output to the browser, I will use the *.php extension. However, if a script contains a mixture of PHP and HTML, I will use the *.phtml extension. This behavior is not "standardized," and the PHP parser will treat both files exactly the same (barring your server is configured to recognize both as PHP files). It's more of a personal preference of the developer.

Really, what you should do is check out the PHP manual, get an introduction to PHP book, or do a few Google searches on getting started with PHP.

Comment: it did work by changing extension and i have got php now, sorry but bad answer.

Comment: No, you do not. Changing the extension to PHP doesn't mean you have a PHP application, unless you have written PHP code in the file. Taking an HTML file with absolutely no PHP in the file and changing the extension *does not* make it a PHP application. Please read about PHP and how it works before you make accusations of a "bad answer." (Source of Knowledge: I'm a Zend PHP Certified Engineer.)

Comment: well i am sorry but it worked for me. i dont care how much certified you are when you cannot explain why it worked. greetings

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the ending of your files to `.php` - now you have a php program, although a very boring one that just outputs static HTML.

Go anywhere inside that HTML and insert:

```
<?php
echo 'This is php, which is ' . (6*7) . ' times cooler than HTML!';
?>
```

Now, reload the page and watch the output php generated.

One more thing: For php code to be executed on the server, you need a server in the first place. If your current URLs start with `file://`, you'll need to install a webserver(for example apache) with php and let your URLs start with `http://localhost/`. You can find more about how to configure php (and your webserver) in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php).

Comment: PHP is actually only about 1.857142857 times as cool as HTML. Switch the `*` to a `/`.

Comment: boss ,very little chance OP has web server installed

Comment: @ajreal Since the OP is linking to his website (or one he created), I wouldn't necessarily say so.